# how to get latest time(not date) in groovy and add 10 mins to it?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

how to get current time(not date) in groovy and add 10 mins to it?
Basically i am trying to get current time and add 10 minutes to it , lastly print

Answer (score 1):

Did you try anything?  This should work

```
import java.time.LocalTime

LocalTime.now().plusMinutes(10).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

It's basically Java